# Hibernate 4.3, when building SessionFactory why do we have to supply the properties twice?

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, configuration, hibernate-4.x

Using the Hibernate 4.3.5 when you want to create a SessionFactory (e.g. unit testing) you will have to supply the properties twice:

1. Once for configuration
2. Second time, when applying settings to the service registry builder

The example looks like:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "sa");
properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .addProperties(properties)
    .addAnnotatedClass(SecurityId.class)
    .buildSessionFactory(
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(properties)
                    .build()
);
```

If I comment:

```
//.addProperties(properties)
```

Then the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property doesn't get thorough:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SECURITYID
```

If I comment:

```
//.applySettings(properties)
```

I the get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Coda available on [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/DriverConnectionProviderTest.java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code, it uses properties from configuration.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(SecurityId.class);
configuration.addProperties(properties);
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: But it's the same thing, the question is why do we need to set those twice?

Comment: Why configuration properties or why service registry properties?

Comment: Why do we need to set the configuration properties, only to supply them as serviceRegistry settings. This is the question. Why not setting them once and that's it.

Comment: We need these properties for the service registry builder, because it doesn't know about configuration it should use its properties.